# Don't stretch img in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I want to stretch the image in ImageView. I use 9path image. This is my code:

```
<FrameLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="18dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/glass_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
</FrameLayout
```

But the resulting image is not stretched (there is a white background around the image). Why?

Comment: remove background color from imageview and change framelayout height into matchparent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Don't set fixed height.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/glass_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/white"
        />
 </FraneLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

change match_parent to wrap_content..

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/glass_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@color/white"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set image as background

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/glass_progress"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:background="@drawable/img"
/>
```

try this also this one will crop the image

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/glass_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@color/white"
    />
```

Comment: also set match_parent in fragment layout